# Set mtime based on date string in filename

Tags: bash, timestamp, filenames

Given a group of files with the following naming convention:

datetime_restofname.txt

an example of which would be:

200906290700_somewordorphrase.txt

how could I batch change the mtime of the files to match the date and time in the filename?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ for f in *.txt; do touch -t `echo $f | cut -f1 -d _` "$f"; done
```

This will set the file modtime to the date string before the underscore.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, sunny256! Sadly, I cannot upvote your excellent reply ("Vote Up requires 15 reputation"), but I deeply appreciate your taking the time to help.

Comment: By the way, it would be awesome if Stack Overflow offered some easy way to shoot you a tip (via PayPal, etc) for your kind help. If you have a PayPal account, please let me know the associated email address - I'd like to beam over some beer money if that's OK.

Comment: Sorry - forgot my email address: miles at tinyapps dot org

Comment: Thanks a lot for the offer, just glad to help. :) I'm also very thankful that we in fact have free software to play around with in the first place, so by sending a small donation to the Free Software Foundation, some organization who works against software patents or something along that line will help keeping it available for free.

But it's a good idea, and SO has sort of implemented it with the bounty feature.

Comment: I slightly modified the script you kindly provided to process files in subdirectories as well:

for f in `find -name *.txt`; do touch -t `echo $f | cut -f1 -d _ | tr -d [:alpha:][:punct:]` "$f"; done

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I just donated $20 to the FSF in your name. Also, can someone please point me to a guide for formatting options on SO? Does HTML work? I noticed that underscores around a word italicize...

Comment: Edit: the donation was in your domain name. It would be swell if SO allowed editing of one's own comments...