# Set mtime based on date string in file

Tags: bash, touch

this is a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066690/set-mtime-based-on-date-string-in-filename).

But I am not good at shell scripting, so I still want to ask you for help...

My situation is a little different: the date string is in the file.

These files (more than 700) are named msg00000.html to msg00721.html. Each one have a line like this:

```
<li><em>Date</em>: Thu, 22 Jul 2010 00:44:57 +0800</li>
```

After a lot of googling, I finally find them out using this:

```
grep "<li><em>Date" msg00000.html | cut -d' ' -f2-7 | tr -d "</li>"
```

The output is exactly what I want:

```
Thu, 22 Ju 2010 00:44:57 +0800
```

And I know use `touch -md "Thu, 22 Ju 2010 00:44:57 +0800" msg00000.html` can modify the mtime.

However, would anyone could help me combining them together? And do this for 723 files...

Thanks...

**Edit**

Well, I finally figured out how to:

```
for f in *.html; do touch -md "$(grep '<li><em>Date' $f | cut -d' ' -f2-7 | sed 's/<\/li>//')" "$f"; done
```

That's quite a long command...

Actually the problem is in the `tr` command. It delete all the characters when using `-d`, not the pattern. So the date `Thu, 22 Ju 2010 00:44:57 +0800` is wrong. It should be `Thu, 22 Jul 2010 00:44:57 +0800`. Yes, there is an "l" missing, which was deleted by `tr -d`. LOL.

Comment: `for f in *.html`... how the hell did I forget about that, I blame lack of sleep :(

Comment: @ furq Have a nice dream :-) As you can see, I live in UTC+8 timezone...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in {0..721}; do touch -md "`grep '<li><em>Date' $(printf 'msg%05d.html' $i) | sed -e 's#<[^>]*>##g' | cut -d' ' -f2-7`" $(printf 'msg%05d.html' $i); done
```

I'm sure an awk guru will be along shortly to show us how to do it in 20 characters, but this should do the trick.

EDIT: Remember, kids, it's important to get some sleep instead of trying to answer questions on the internet.  You don't want to end up posting ridiculous answers like this, do you?

Comment: Thank you for your quick help! But there is something wrong...It says <code>touch: invalid date format `Thu, 22 Ju 2010 00:44:57 +0800'</code>. And I am trying to use <code>for f in *.html; do touch -md "$(grep '<li><em>Date' $f | cut -d' ' -f2-7 | tr -d '</li>')" "$f"; done</code> too. They have the same error. Maybe there are too many quotation marks...

Comment: Should've tested that properly; `tr -d "</li>"` was breaking it as it removes the l from "Jul".  I've edited the answer, it ought to work now.

Comment: @wzyboy : If furq has solved your problem, you should accept his answer, thus giving him reputation points. Recall that rep points don't debit your rep-points. ;-) Good luck to all.